# How to filter Spring boot actuator metrics?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Spring boot actuator metrics (`/actuator/metrics`) comes with many default metrics. Some of them are:

```
"jvm.memory.max",
"jvm.threads.states",
"process.files.max",
"jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
"tomcat.servlet.error",
"system.load.average.1m",
"jvm.memory.used",
"jvm.gc.max.data.size",
"jvm.memory.committed",
"http.server.requests",
"system.cpu.count",
"logback.events",
"tomcat.global.sent",
...
```

Is it possible to expose only few of them? (i.e. filtering them or better yet, telling Spring boot not to collect them at all?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `management.metrics.enable.*` properties to control the metrics that are enabled and bound to the meter registry. Where a metric's name is `.` separated, you can disable multiple metrics with a single property. For example, to disable all `jvm` properties you can use the following property:

```
management.metrics.enable.jvm=false
```

Where there are multiple properties that match the same metric, the most-specific wins. For example, to disable all `jvm` metrics other than `jvm.memory.max`, you can use the following properties:

```
management.metrics.enable.jvm=false
management.metrics.enable.jvm.memory.max=true
```

You can use `all` to match all metrics. For example, to disable all metrics other than `jvm.memory` metrics, you can use the following properties:

```
management.metrics.enable.all=false
management.metrics.enable.jvm.memory=true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy!

Comment: by the way, can you also filter by "availableTags"? i.e. measure only `logback.events.level.error`

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You'll have to write some code though. Define a bean that implements `io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.MeterFilter` and it'll be registered automatically.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Is there any spring reference doc where I can find all properties related to metrics? I tried but was not able to find.

Comment: @mohitsahu Have you seen https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.actuator?